# Android onSharedPreferencesChanged is triggerd when Preferences activity starts for first time

Tags: android

I have registered an onSharedPreferencesChanged Listener for my app. If i Install my app for first time the sharedPreferencesChanged Listener is triggered but it shouldn't.

Here is my code:

```
onSharedPrefChangedListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(key.equals(ENABLE_BANNER_AD_PREFERENCE_KEY)){
        Toast.makeText(FragmentTabsPager.this,getString(R.string.will_disable_restart), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        };
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onSharedPrefChangedListener);
```

and thats in Preferences XML :

```
 <CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/title"
                        android:summary="@string/summary"
                        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                        android:defaultValue="true"
                         android:key="bannerKey"> </CheckBoxPreference>
```

The Toast appears when i start the app for first time aftern an installation. If i start the application again and navigate to the Preferences the preferencesListener will not triggered.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO what the system does is the right behavior.

But you should be able to introduce a flag to distinguish between the very first invocation and the subsequent ones.

Comment: Maybe its the right behavior. But i didnt understand why its only after a first launch?..

Comment: Try to remove application data. Will the preferences listener be invoked?

Comment: I think the problem is that the  android:defaultValue="true" attribute will set from Preferences aktivity in first launch.. so the listener will called always when in the preferences nothing added with the preference key.. Now..  don't know how to solve this problem:)

Comment: It means that when there is no application data, the preferences have changed (and the previous state was either something-that-was-deleted or no-application-on-device). Very logical.

Comment: As to the solution, you might introduce a boolean flag in the shared preferences, say, "already_launched". When the listener is invoked, you check if that flag is present. If (the flag is not there or false), {this is the 1st launch; you set the flag to true and do nothing} else {it is a subsequent launch; you do whatever you wanted to do}

Comment: something like if(prefs.getBoolean("already_was_launched", false)) {...} else {prefs.edit().putBoolean("already_was_launched", true).commit();}